# Apache Rewrite: rewrite ONLY index URLs regardless of depth with file extension exceptions

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this somewhat working though it's important to understand the setup.

With multi-domain support (multiple domains using the exact same copy of software) I need to rewrite ONLY the directories (which end cleanly like dir1/ or dir2/).

Visually here are where the files are referenced...

**site1.com/gallery/image.jpg**

**site2.net/gallery/image.png**

**gallery/** (PHP code here)

**.htaccess**

So I want to have only directories rewritten to gallery/ while all image files (by extension) are rewritten to the site1/gallery/image.jpg paths.

What I have currently rewrites ONLY the base gallery/ path however it does NOT rewrite deeper gallery indexes (e.g. gallery/my_gallery/) however the image exception does work as well.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/gallery/$ gallery/$1 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png)$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/(gallery|admin|blog)
RewriteRule !\.(css|js)$ index.php
```

So how to I capture all directories regardless of depth while maintaining the image file exception please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was add the file extensions to the rewrite condition. Also it's VERY important to note that the rewrite condition *must* appear *before* the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|mp3|png|swf|xml)$
RewriteRule ^[^/]*/(gallery|admin|blog)(.+) $1$2 [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/(gallery|admin|blog)
RewriteRule !\.(css|js)$ index.php
```